Why is this integral not zero?
I am trying to understand the why the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx$$
does not converge, specifically why it is not equal to zero. Graph of Function
Looking at the graph of the function it would seem the the integral will be zero as the area below the x-axis is equal to the area above the x-axis.
The reasoning I used to solve this integral was:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx$$
$$= \lim_{a \to \infty} \ [\ln|x|]_{x=-a}^{x=a}$$
$$= 0$$
Also, Since $\frac{1}{x}$ is an odd function the integral should be zero. Finally, because I thought the the problem with the previous reasonings mights be that they do not work around zero. I came up with the following explanation for why it should still be zero.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx$$
$$ = \lim_{a \to 0}({\int_{-\infty}^{-a}\frac{1}{x}dx + \int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx})$$
$$ = 0 $$
edit: Ok so I have found that the reason this doesn't work is because you can write the integral above as $$ = \lim_{a \to 0}({\int_{-\infty}^{-a}\frac{1}{x}dx + \int_{2a}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx})$$
which clearly does not converge, However I don't understand why this requirement exists for the integral to be convergent?
is it necessarily true $$\lim_{a \to 0} f(a) = \lim_{a \to 0} f(ka)$$ $k$ is any real number non-zero number?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. The fact the integral has two infinite integration bounds introduces some subtleties. (Such bounds are often called limits, but given the other meaning of that term here it's probably best to just call them integration bounds.)

This improper integral diverges according to the definiton found in your calculus textook.  Look it up.  In this case, there is a "principal value" which is $0$.  That topic is likely too advanced for your calculus textbook.
